# CREATE VIEW syntax for WITH AS (SELECT) statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, syntax

SQL Server: I have the following working SQL statement:

```
WITH required_skills AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        e.empl_ID, e.job_code, j.skill_ID, j.skill_desc
    FROM 
        emplskills e
    JOIN 
        jobskills j ON e.job_code = j.job_code
)
SELECT 
    r.empl_ID, e.emplName, r.job_code, r.skill_ID, r.skill_desc
FROM
    required_skills r
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    emplskills e ON r.empl_ID = e.empl_ID
                 AND r.skill_ID = e.skill_ID;
```

I would like to convert the output of this statement to a view. I thought I could just do this:

```
CREATE VIEW MY_VIEW 
AS
    (WITH required_skills AS
     (
         SELECT DISTINCT 
             e.empl_ID, e.job_code, j.skill_ID, j.skill_desc
         FROM 
             emplskills e
         JOIN 
             jobskills j ON e.job_code = j.job_code
     )
     SELECT 
         r.empl_ID, e.emplName, r.job_code, r.skill_ID, r.skill_desc
     FROM 
         required_skills r
     FULL OUTER JOIN 
         emplskills e ON r.empl_ID = e.empl_ID AND r.skill_ID = e.skill_ID
);
```

But it errors out with this :

> Incorrect syntax near 'WITH'

Can someone help please?

TIA,
John

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis after AS.

```
CREATE VIEW MyViewName
AS
WITH required_skills as (
      SELECT DISTINCT e.empl_ID, e.job_code, j.skill_ID, j.skill_desc
     FROM emplskills e
     JOIN jobskills j
       ON e.job_code = j.job_code
)
SELECT r.empl_ID, e.emplName, r.job_code, r.skill_ID, r.skill_desc
  FROM required_skills r
       FULL OUTER JOIN emplskills e
       ON r.empl_ID = e.empl_ID
      AND r.skill_ID = e.skill_ID
```

Comment: bingo. Thank you Sir!

Comment: `WITH` has to be the first statement in the batch. I usually try to make sure my CTEs begin with `; WITH` just to make sure.

Comment: @Shawn they don't need to be the first statement in the batch. `SELECT 1; WITH CTE AS (SELECT 1 AS I) SELECT I FROM CTE;` will run fine. What you have to do is **terminate the previous statement** in the batch with a semicolon (`;`). The semicolon is not a "beginningator".

Comment: `SELECT 1`**`;`**'WITH CTE...` has a semicolon in it, terminating `SELECT 1`, then the `WITH CTE` is started.

Comment: Glad it worked for you @JohnJoseph … be sure to mark as answer.

Comment: @Shawn `;` isn't a batch separator. It's a statement separator.  `GO` in SSMS and `sqlcmd` is a batch separator. They are completely different things. A batch and statement should not be confused. If `;` were a batch separator then `DECLAFE @I = 1; SELECT 1;` wouldn't work, as the variables was declared in a separate batch. It wasn't.

Comment: And sorry. Bad terminology on my part. `;` terminates a statement. `GO` terminates a batch. `WITH` needs to be the first term in the statement. I use the `;` to make sure there is nothing else running in front of it.

Comment: Again, not true @Shawn. `Select 1 WITH CTE AS (SELECT 1 AS I) SELECT I FROM CTE` is 2 statements. The problem is the first was not terminated.

Comment: @Larnu That's essentially what I just said. And I don't believe `SELECT 1 WITH CTE...` will compile on SQL Server. It may compile in other languages, but a CTE should be the first thing in a statement.

Comment: @Shawn it won't, I implied that.:) As I said, the key thing is that the previous statement t is terminated with a semicolon. That's because not ending statements with a semicolon is deprecated. Starting a `WITH` expression with a semicolon isn't really adhering to that deprecating; it's not (as I said) a "beginningator". :)

Comment: @Larnu I think we're saying the same thing. Again, sorry for the bad terminology in my original statement. It apparently caused more confusion than I intended.